# c# entity use between to show value

Tags: c#, entity

i have this code writing in c# entity frame work code first:

```
 if (checkBox3.Checked)
 {
      li = li.Where(c => c.YearO > textFirst.Text && c.YearO < textLast.Text).AsEnumerable();
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = li.ToList();
 dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

YearO has int values from DataBase 
textFirst : values to begin search 
textLast : values to end searsh

how to show YearO values between textFirst (begin value to search ) and 
textLast (end value to search) ?

like SQL :

```
select YearO,  from DB where 
              c.yearO >= textFirst and c.yearO <= textLast
```

Comment: So?  What is your question?  I don't see a single question mark anywhere....

Comment: I need to do ***. This makes no sense. I have no clue what you want to do or how to help you. Are you trying to get data from a database? A variable?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand what u want exactly.

perhaps u want

```
li = li.Where(c => c.YearO > Convert.ToIn32(textFirst.Text) && c.YearO < Convert.ToIn32(textLast.Text)).select(s => s.YEarO)
```

Comment: No i need to select every data between 2 day (textFirst.text && textlast.text)
like this : 

select YearO,  from DB where 
              c.yearO >= textFirst and c.yearO <= textLast